# Why cooler water or air feels "cooler" than comparatively less cool water or air?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Why  air sometimes  feels more cooler than air in othertime.

I mean like why Cooler water feels cooler than  comparatively less cooler water.

Does the heat transfer rate increase in cooler air or water than in less cooler water air or air?

If yes then how could heat transfer rate increase for a given same material say water? Does it?

I can understand that a cooler body(example cool water) will absorb more heat to evaporate than comparatively less cooler water which already has some energy so I will take comparatively less time to evaporate. But my friend told me that **"we feel comparative temperature(cooler or hotter) by sensation that is what we feel in a unit time(heat transfer rate, if more heat absorb  in a unit time than we feel more cool) not depend what we are going to feel in next hour after complete absorption of heat and evaporating full amount finally."**

So if we take water as an example One bowl with cooler water than water in other bowl same amount , the water in first bowl will feel cooler than other ? Why ? Does heat transfer rate(per unit) increase in first bowl water? But how can same material (although I don't learn these topics still it is not logical that a same material start absorbing more heat in unit time when cool but logically it can absorb more heat with sane rate thus taking more time in evaporating), I mean same water amount start absorbing more heat per unit time say a second.

I can totally agree that bowl in first water will absorb more heat than water in 2nd bowl as it needed more energy to evaporate, but will it take more heat in unit time, if it will! then more cooler water shouldn't take much time to evaporate!! But it doesn't happen. Right!

So what's going on . Why cooler water feels "cooler" than less cool water ? Or why cooler air feels "cooler" then less cool air?  Same why metals in cooler environment feels 'cooler' than metal in less cool environment ?

Or my friend is wrong that what we feel (sensation) cooler or less cool, warmer or less warm depend on **per unit time absorption of heat**!!??

- heat source is constant*

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level, the idea is that the rate of heat transfer from one object to another is proportional to the temperature difference between the two bodies; this is often referred to as [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling).  So more heat moves per unit time from your body into a cooler fluid than into the same fluid at a higher temperature.

Comment: So if difference is more than more heat/ unit time ? And vice versa for less difference ! Right?? In which standard it will be taught to us?